# Are there any tools which can generate code from the debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mocking, visual-studio-debugging, automated-refactoring

I'm thinking of an equivalent refactor of ?variable in the immediate window in VS2010 Can something take that output or by means of another mechanism and create code to generate that object and it's properties (recursively).

I'm looking into making some live 'mock' objects which I can use for our integration testing and this functionality would make it a lot easier.

**Update:** basically checking whether it can do the following...

```
MyObject
    AddressModel = MyAddressModel,
    AllowChangeDatasets = false,
```

to

```
public class MyObject
{
     public AddressModel AddressModel { get; set;}
     public bool AllowChangeDatasets { get; set; }
}

MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.AddressModel = new MyAddressModel()
{
    // bla bla
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks)?

> Rhino Mocks is a dynamic mock object framework for the .Net platform.
>   Its purpose is to ease testing by allowing the developer to create
>   mock implementations of custom objects and verify the interactions
>   using unit testing.